# Adding and printing very small numbers in R

Tags: r, for-loop, floating-point

I'm running a for loop in R to see whether adding up halves of the previous half eventually reaches 1 (.5 + .25 + .125 + .0625 +  .03125,...) using the code below:

```
temp = 0
for(i in 2^seq(1, 60, by = 1))  { 
  temp = temp + 1/i
  print(sprintf("%.40f", temp))
  flush.console()
  }
```

but, past the 54th iteration, it does reach one, but it's apparently not adding things any more (even increasing the %.40f parameter):

```
result.52 "0.9999999999999997779553950749686919152737"
result.53 "0.9999999999999998889776975374843459576368"
result.54 "1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
result.55 "1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
result.56 "1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
result.57 "1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
result.58 "1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
result.59 "1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

How can I print all digits? I guess that's got to do with deeper knowledge of R's math standards

Comment: If you want more than double precision floating point numbers, there are packages like this one: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/vignettes/Rmpfr-pkg.pdf

Comment: Doubles are coded with 53 bits. This is the reason. nothing happens after iteration  54.

Comment: Mathematically it never reaches 1 except in the limit. But along a finite number of terms will always be below 1

Comment: @Dason That's what I was wondering, anyway just wanted to show it in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package `Rmpfr` can get more digits of precision. In the example below I will use 100 digits of precision.

```
library(Rmpfr)

d <- 100
zero <- mpfr(0, precBits = d)
one <- mpfr(1, precBits = d)
powers <- mpfr(2^(1:60), precBits = d)

result <- vector("list", length = length(powers))
temp2 <- zero
for(i in seq_along(powers)) {
  temp2 = temp2 + one/powers[i]
  iszero <- mpfrIs0(one/powers[i])
  result[[i]] <- list(Exp = i, InvIsZero = iszero, Sum = temp2)
}
```

In the question the OP says that

> past the 54th iteration, it does reach one, but it's apparently not
>   adding things any more (even increasing the %.40f parameter).

Apparently this has to do with `sprintf`, not with the results.
With the `print.mpfr` method:

```
for(i in 52:60){
  print(result[[i]][[3]], digits = 60)
  flush.console()
}
#1 'mpfr' number of precision  100   bits 
#[1] 0.9999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375
#1 'mpfr' number of precision  100   bits 
#[1] 0.99999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875
#1 'mpfr' number of precision  100   bits 
#[1] 0.999999999999999944488848768742172978818416595458984375
#1 'mpfr' number of precision  100   bits 
#[1] 0.9999999999999999722444243843710864894092082977294921875
#1 'mpfr' number of precision  100   bits 
#[1] 0.99999999999999998612221219218554324470460414886474609375
#1 'mpfr' number of precision  100   bits 
#[1] 0.999999999999999993061106096092771622352302074432373046875
#1 'mpfr' number of precision  100   bits 
#[1] 0.9999999999999999965305530480463858111761510372161865234375
#1 'mpfr' number of precision  100   bits 
#[1] 0.99999999999999999826527652402319290558807551860809326171875
#1 'mpfr' number of precision  100   bits 
#[1] 0.999999999999999999132638262011596452794037759304046630859375
```

With `sprintf`:

```
for(i in 52:60){
  print(sprintf("%d - %.60f", i, result[[i]][[3]]))
  flush.console()
}
#[1] "52 - 0.999999999999999777955395074968691915273666381835937500000000"
#[1] "53 - 0.999999999999999888977697537484345957636833190917968750000000"
#[1] "54 - 1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
#[1] "55 - 1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
#[1] "56 - 1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
#[1] "57 - 1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
#[1] "58 - 1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
#[1] "59 - 1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
#[1] "60 - 1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```